# how to add a disclosure panel to a cellTable column in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a cellTable with 5-6 columns. I want to put a plus icon in each row on clicking of which will display the details maybe in a disclosure panel. I have been looking around for a while now and I cannot find any information on how to achieve this. Could someone point me in the right direction?

i suspect  i probably have to add a cellTree to the column? how do i go about this? 
Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is work in progress to allow expandable rows in CellTable among other features (maybe GWT 2.3). You can see more details here:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/b4a8a6e3c98ac061#

If that is not enough or you can not wait untill it is released I can think of two ways to achieve it:

- As you said, using a CellTree.
- Creating a custom cell that stores
  state (open/close). Depending on the
  state the cell will render
  differently. In same way it is
  similar to how EditTextCell works, in
  "edit" state it renders an input
  field while in "normal" state it renders
  simple text.

Comment: I can't really wait for the release 2.3. So I was thinking about a custom cell too. I can't think of a way to attach the disclosure panel to a row though. If I did add the disclosure to the cellTree in a cell I wonder how it would be displayed.

Comment: [looks like](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6328) this will make it to 2.5. But I am also doubt that would be a good replacement for disclosure-like appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do that too ... I managed to mimic that functionality toying with the html and a custom cell class that allows clickable pictures.
It is working for normal content such as text but if you'd like to get an asynchronous data to show in the expended line, I don't know how to do it ... (I'm trying to do exactly that).

Also, it doesn't look good because the columns don't align well ...

So what I've done is:
- create a custom cell class to display a picture (right pointing triangle, looking like the triangle in the disclosure panel)

- In the click event get the HTML code of the selected row and copy it. Replace the content of the row (all cells) in the table with only one cell with its colspan set to number of columns. In the cell, add a table with first line the copied row and second line the content to display as expanded.
- Get the image to sink an event for closing. In event, reset the original row that we copied.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have been trying to do a similar thing. Still halfway through. I have been distracted with another project. I hope I can get back to complete this soon..